# Is there a way to duplicate a worksheet using gspread in python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

So I've been trying to create a data store using google sheets (It's easier for me to navigate). The way I'm trying to do this is by creating a new worksheet with the user's ID and putting the information I have saved in a separate worksheet called 'template' into the new worksheet.

This is my current code:

```
newsheet = sh.add_worksheet(title = f"{author}", rows = "152", cols = "2")
for index in range(1, len(savefiletemplate.col_values(1))):
    newsheet.update_cell(index, 1, savefiletemplate.cell(index, 1).value)
```

`author` is the user's ID, `sh` is my spreadsheet and `savefiletemplate` is my template worksheet

It gives me a very long error that I don't understand after copying 90-120 cells. I was wondering if this is my fault or my IDE's fault and if anyone knows how to fix it

Comment: Add the error message.

Comment: it says message is too long by 2000

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this...

```
rows = 152
cols = 2
template_data = savefiletemplate.get_all_values()  # this will be a list of lists
newsheet = sh.add_worksheet(title=author, rows=rows, cols=cols)
a1_range = f"A1:{chr(ord('@')+cols)}{rows}"  # A1:B152
newsheet.update(a1_range, template_data)
```

This basically takes your template and puts it into a list of lists.  Then uses the `rows` and `cols` value to build the proper a1 notation for the range.  Then updates the range in the new sheet with the `template_data`.  Give it a shot and see if it does what you're looking for.